# Refresh Div automatically after every 5 sec

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

i have to update div tag after every 5 second
For this i need to read local .txt file and show that output to web page as when .txt is update then that data should load in web page using html and javascript
I am using flask server

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var refreshDiv = setInterval(
    function(){
    var fs = require('fs');
    // var text = fs.readFileSync("static/output.txt");
    var text = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'txt', 'static/output.txt'))
    var textByLine = text.split("\n")

        testByLine = testByLine + 1;
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "aaa" + testByLine;
        location.reload(true);
      }, 4000;
</script>
```

Comment: What the error you are facing? It seems to me that you are missing `);` after `4000;`. It should be `4000);`

Comment: Yeah. as @Anonymous said. it's a syntax error i guess. just add ) after 4000. it should work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The various ways of doing this but what I like to do is keep the neatness of the code  so I put the method in a function  .

```
//embed the code here 
function runMycode(){
    var fs = require('fs');
    // var text = fs.readFileSync("static/output.txt");
    var text = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'txt', 'static/output.txt'))
    var textByLine = text.split("\n")

        testByLine = testByLine + 1;
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "aaa" + testByLine;
        location.reload(true);
}
```

If you want to run it multiple times

```
//set the timeout function and run the code
setInterval(function(){
   runMyCode();
}, 30000);
```

or in the case you want to run it once

```
setTimeout(function() {   
  runMyCode();
}, 50000);
```

And if you wanted to do it in the browser can do it for you if you add this meta tag in your head tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work i guess you are missing the closing braces of setInterval

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var refreshDiv = setInterval(
    function(){
    var fs = require('fs');
    // var text = fs.readFileSync("static/output.txt");
    var text = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'txt', 'static/output.txt'))
    var textByLine = text.split("\n")

        testByLine = testByLine + 1;
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "aaa" + testByLine;
        location.reload(true);
      }, 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are missing `);` after `4000;`. It should be `4000)`;

As a result, your code should look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var refreshDiv = setInterval(
    function(){
    var fs = require('fs');
    // var text = fs.readFileSync("static/output.txt");
    var text = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'txt', 'static/output.txt'))
    var textByLine = text.split("\n")

        testByLine = testByLine + 1;
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "aaa" + testByLine;
        location.reload(true);
      }, 4000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you add the file contents to the div just clear the div contents. I don't think you need to use `location.reload`. just clear the div.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var refreshDiv = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "aaa"
    var text =  
    fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'txt','static/output.txt'));
    var textByLine = text.split("\n")

    testByLine = testByLine + 1;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "aaa" + testByLine;
}, 5000);
```

And also don't require `fs` library every 5 seconds. make it public.

**NOTE:** you missed `)` end of the function.